# Order of automorphism of Projective special linear group

Tags: gr.group-theory

What is the order of $Aut(PSL(3,4))$?

Answer (score 1):

Gap computes in in a couple seconds, or find it in the Atlas

http://brauer.maths.qmul.ac.uk/Atlas/v3/scripts/group2.php?id=184&subpage=1

The outer automorphism group is D12, the full automorphism group has order 12*20160.

Comment: Or use the theory of automorphism groups of Chevalley groups. There is a diagonal automorphism of order $(3,4-1) = 3$, a field automorphism of order 2 (since $4=2^2$) and a graph automorphism of order 2.